# Create a clickable span for each word in a JSON subtitle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On my website I have a couple of videos along with their subtitles in **JSON** format.

I have linked the subtitles with the video, and now I want to make each word of each active subtitle appear in a clickable span element, so that when a user hovers on each span they see the meaning of that word and if they click on it they see some more information on the right panel.

So far I've written the code below and linked the subtitle with my video :

The **HTML** :

```
<video id="example_video" class="" controls preload="none" width="640" height="400">
        <source src="{% static 'office.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>

    <div>
        <h3 id="subs" style="color: rgb(21, 31, 63); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;"></h3>
    </div>

</body>
```

The **Javascript**:

```
<script>
            var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video");
            var subtitles = document.getElementById("subs");

            var sub_info = [{'start': 3.92, 'end': 6.84, 'text': ['a word', 'another word', 'a word again'], 'definitions': []}]

            videoPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", myFunc);
            
            function myFunc() {
                const activeSubtitle = sub_info.find(
                    (sub) =>
                    parseFloat(sub.start) <= videoPlayer.currentTime &&
                    parseFloat(sub.end) >= videoPlayer.currentTime
                );
                if (activeSubtitle) {
                    subtitles.innerHTML = activeSubtitle.text;
                } 
                else {
                    subtitles.innerHTML = " ";
                }
                }
 </script>
```

**sub_info** is where I put my **JSON subtitle** with their timestamps.

It's working fine and appends the subtitles to div element in the correct time.

Now I have split the text by each word using python and I want to create a span for each word in sub_info and make each span a clickable and hoverable element(on hover show short definition, on click show full definition).

I want to scrape and append the definitions of each word to **sub_info['definitions']**, so it should read the definitions from there. I guess there should be a better approach for this purpose though!

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you try your own idea? Create a span for each word and append a hover effect on it? Your question does not contain an actual coding problem.

Comment: I think the question is just a bit unclear. What part exactly are you stuck on? Don't you know how to loop through an array of words? Or creating a span? Or linking a word to a definition in another array? If you try to make a start doing this, you can post the actual errors/problems you get here on stackoverflow.